# Help Installing psycopg2 on snow leopard : command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

Tags: gcc, osx-snow-leopard, installation, psycopg2

This has been driving me crazy for 2 days.

I have been trying to install psycopg2 using easy_install and no matter what I try (i.e using gcc-4.0 instead of the snow leopard default one) I always get the same error:

error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

Please see: http://dpaste.com/hold/228252/

I have googled that error so many times and nothing I have found seem to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a dependency, the development files for `libpq`. The relevant log part is here:

> In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:32In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:32:
>   ./psycopg/psycopg.h:31:22: error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory

Try installing libpq development files and then rerun easy_install.  You may hit another missing dependency; pay attention to the first error that GCC spits out.

Comment: I added export PATH=/Library/PostgresPlus/8.4SS/bin/:$PATH to ~/.bash_profile, then I rerun easy_install and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Link http://dpaste.com/hold/228252/ seems to be dead, this is how I solved this problem (Mac OS X 10.6, virtualenv).

If pip fails with this message, just take a look to build folder in your virtual environment. You should edit setup.cfg file there, particularly **include_dirs** and **library_dirs**. In first one set your include folders, my option was:

**include_dirs=/opt/local/include/postgresql84:/opt/local/include/postgresql84/server**

and most likely you will need to set library_dirs to correct location as well:

**library_dirs=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84**.

Answer (score 1):

probably you should install  postgresql-devel first
`yum -y install postgresql-devel`